# showing barcode font in .net application

Tags: c#, fonts, barcode, setup-deployment

I have added a barcode font in my one crystal report of C# .Net application and it worked fine in develop and shown the result. But when I created the setup file and installed it in another pc then the barcode font appears as simple font as english alphabet although I have installed barcode font.

So will you please help me to show barcode font on exe after installing my application?

Comment: This post should assist:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727053/how-do-i-embed-a-font-with-my-c-sharp-application-using-visual-studio-2005

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spire.barcode http://freebarcode.codeplex.com/ to set barcode image borders, border colors, style, margins and width easily. maybe it can solve your problem, you can have a try to test the component.