# Do I need to embed fonts for use on different computers?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I'm wonder if I use labels or textBoxes with font that I've on my PC but I can't be sure that every user will have it. Different font means different Text size... I mean wide and etc. Pretty hard to do pixel - perfect design. So am I need to embed this fonts into .exe file or what?

Or I've to choose font that I'm 100% sure everyone have?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/727053/799558)!

Comment: @AbZy Not a duplicate as this concerns WPF specifically.

Comment: @Lukazoid I don't think that would really matter, its just a matter of installing a new font in the client pc.

Comment: @AbZy That isn't a duplicate - this user is talking about a system font not a custom one.

Comment: @AbZy WPF does not require installation of a new font, fonts can be embedded into the application and used successfully without installation.

Comment: I'm so sorry if it's duplicate, half of my question was something about to ensure that I need embed fonts. And the second half in general is a duplicate of how to do that right. Cause I was talking about system fonts, not a custom one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.100).aspx) is the MSDN article on how to embed fonts into a WPF application in a variety of ways. If you cannot be sure the font you are using will be available on an end-user machine, use one of the approaches outlined in the article.

Comment: Thank you for useful and fast response!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the font as resource and try it like this

Create a folder name Fonts and copy the font which you want and change the BuildAction to Resource

use it like as below

```
<Window.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="test" >/Fonts/#Pirulen</FontFamily>
</Window.Resources>


<TextBlock FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               FontFamily="{StaticResource test}">data</TextBlock>
```

Check full post : http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/05/14/How-do-I-use-a-custom-font-in-my-WPF-application.aspx