# Saving custom font in resources VISUAL BASIC

Tags: vb.net

I saved my downloaded font in resources and want it to be set on certain checkbox whenever the program is loaded.

I've already tried this:

```
Checkbox1.Font = My.Resources.Allstar
```

("Allstar" is the name of the font ofc)

but it gives me an error:

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Font)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727053/how-do-i-embed-a-font-with-my-c-sharp-application-using-visual-studio-2005

Comment: see also here http://bobpowell.net/embedfonts.aspx

Comment: @Kogitsune please realize that the "Possible duplicate" that you mention is a C# question while his is on the basis of VB.net. Two different languages mind you.

Comment: @Richard Paulicelli That use the same framework and classes. The question might have been for C#, but the solution outlined there works in Visual Basic as well.

Answer (score 3):

Load the resource into a [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) object.  Something like this should be close:

```
    Dim lstPrivateFontCollection As New System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection

    Dim objPointer As IntPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.Allstar.length)

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.Allstar, 0, objPointer, My.Resources.Allstar.Length)

    lstPrivateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont(objPointer, My.Resources.Allstar.Length)

    'Omit next line due to instability pointed out in comments by Hans Passant.
    'It was used to free memory, but could cause app to crash.
    'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(objPointer)

    Dim objFont As New System.Drawing.Font(lstPrivateFontCollection.Families(0), 16.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)

    lstPrivateFontCollection.Dispose()

    Checkbox1.Font = objFont
```

Comment: It freaking works! I only had to put your code in my form_load. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: It doesn't, the FreeCoTaskMem() call will randomly crash your program.  It must not be made until the font can no longer be used.

Comment: I meant it is working when I change my Checkbox font to some random one and it automatically changes back to Allstar without any errors. Now I am sending exe to my friend so maybe it works for him too.

Comment: Thanks for the warning on the FreeCoTaskMem() @HansPassant

Comment: Yep, so @HansPassant was right. It doesn't work for my friend as he doesn't have this font.

Comment: It should come through as an embedded resource.  If you sent him just the code without the resource it won't work.  The FreeCoTaskMem() should not be called where I originally had it though due to possible instabilities.

Comment: So how to do it so he can see the font? I have to send him the .ttf file and he has to put it in control panel>fonts or is there an easier way? I thought the resource thing stores things that are loaded when you run the exe. Now I'm confused :/ The weird thing is that it works good with images, I mean I have 2 images in resources and he can see without having them on drive. How is this working?